# Simple Xml Framework not behaving as expected

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I have this XML string:

```
String str = "<order id='1234'><orderlines><orderline id='567'>"+
"<article id='890'><description>Bananen</description><todo>45</todo>"+
"</article></orderline></orderlines></order>";
```

that I want to read in using simple-framework version 2.7.1. It works OK until the `orderline` class, which looks like this:

```
public class Orderline {
    @Attribute
    public int id;

    @Element
    public Article article;
}
```

I would expect the `description` and `todo` element to "go" into `Article`, but I get this error:

> 05-08 22:45:23.958: D/debug(14854): Element 'description' does not have a match in class nl.rd.svgtest.Orderline at line 1

I parse like this:

```
Serializer s = new Persister();
Order o = s.read(Order.class, str);
```

adding `false` to the `s.read()` call has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, here on SO: [Java : Simple XML not parsing the xml. Gives Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121206/java-simple-xml-not-parsing-the-xml-gives-exception)

I had to add `(inline=true)` to my `ElementList`, as also shown in the [tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).